# Temporal topological sort of NetworkX graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have a [NetworkX graph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) which was constructed using simple node and edge types, with the addition of a timestamp field on nodes:

```py
class Node:
  key: str
  timestamp: int

class Edge:
  n1: Node # Source node
  n2: Node # Target node
```

Here's an example of constructing such a graph assuming I already have a list of `edges` and a list of `nodes`:

```py
graph = nx.DiGraph()
for e in edges:
    graph.add_edge(e.n1, e.n2)
for n in nodes:
    graph.add_node(n.key, timestamp=n.timestamp)
```

- The graph is a "git graph-like" entity and the timestamp represents a "commit date". I want a topological sort that also "respects" dates, so am I correct to assume that [lexicographical topological sort](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.lexicographical_topological_sort.html) is the tool for the job, i.e. it sorts topologically and break ties using the date?
- What is the correct way to invoke this algorithm? I'm trying :

  ```py
  networkx.lexicographical_topological_sort(graph, key=lambda n: n.timestamp)
  ```

  but the `timestamp` information was provided as keyword argument to the node constructor. The documentation only mentions cases where the lambda directly utilizes the node. Am I correct to assume I can access its members, or is it converted to a string (or hash) by the time my lambda function accesses it?

Comment: minor point:your class type hint should be str, not string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't have a problem accessing its members, the following is a broadcast tree (height 1):

```
import networkx as nx
class Node:
  def __init__(self,key,ts):
    self.key=key
    self.timestamp=ts

class Edge:
  def __init__(self,n1,n2):
    self.n1=n1
    self.n2=n2

listnodes = [Node("root",-1)]+[Node("dummy name",random.randint(2,10000))  for i in range(9)]
listedges = [Edge(listnodes[0],listnodes[i+1]) for i in range(9)]
for x in nx.lexicographical_topological_sort(G, key=lambda n: n.timestamp):
  print(x.key,x.timestamp)
G = nx.DiGraph()
for e in listedges:
    G.add_edge(e.n1, e.n2)
list(G.nodes(data=True))
for x in nx.lexicographical_topological_sort(G, key=lambda n: n.timestamp):
  print(x.key,x.timestamp)
```

if i run it i get:

```
root -1
dummy name 65
dummy name 414
dummy name 686
dummy name 2328
dummy name 3031
dummy name 3651
dummy name 4023
dummy name 4153
dummy name 7710
```